# Windows 7 Defaults program to Volume 13 on external input?

Tags: windows, audio

I have noticed that i'm using spotify on my Windows machine. The problem which i'm coming for assistance is that whenver I put any form of external storage/input to my machine.. Be it USB or CD.. My Spotify sound volume takes its self down to 13.

I'm unable to give steps to reproduce this type of problem.. other than insert a USB to a USB slot > Volume decreases to 13 (by Windows sound settings)

Comment: "I have noticed that i'm using spotify on my Windows machine" - So you didn't know already? Sounds like you just discovered this! ;) Anyway, have you reported this on the Spotify forum yet? This could very well be a bug in the software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall there is a selectable option on the sound sources such that allows windows to automatically decrease the volume in certain cases.  I can't remember exactly where this option was, but look at the Control Panel->Sound and in the details of each of the source sources.

Comment: If you're talking about `right-click Speaker icon in tray / Sounds / Communications tab`, I've never *ever* seen that trigger due to a USB drive being plugged in. Also, the question seems to indicate that only Spotify's volume is reduced, whereas this OS option affects the master volume.